# How to disable computer (laptop, desktop, thin client) without damaging it?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, desktop-computer, diagnostic

I need to seriously train my people on computer hardware diagnosis. To that end i need to have several computers - laptops, desktops, thin clients, AIOs - that appear to be damaged and/or faulty.
So, hoping they do not read this (they're not good English speakers, let alone native, so chances are even), here it goes:

How to make laptop inoperable without damaging it? Obviously, I accept the risks that the solution may actually cause damage, but I think i can spare some really old stuff for that particular risky case.
Also, components are fair game - ram sticks, drives, cables are expendable, as long as they do not pose cascading failure risk.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to prepare some scenarios for your colleagues to try and solve? You want to 'injure' a client machine, and have them diagnose and repair it?

Comment: While I was at school one of my teachers did these types of exercises, there is endless ways to make a computer not boot, loosening essential cables, RAM badly placed, remove the CPU and mount the fan, remove the on/off jumper, etc.

Comment: Install a known dead PSU and or a known bad stick of ram.

Comment: @spikey_richie - yes. But really "injure". Basically greatest would be computer not responding at all.

Comment: @Moab - ah, but nowadays you will get beep codes for all that. And I know how to do that. At this point I have 8 years experience in teardown and diagnosis. I want to make a point that one needs to use brain occasionally, not just manuals.

Comment: No necessarily, bad ram can still work but cause boot issues, same with PSU's, depends on the defect.

Answer (score 1):

- You could get one ram stick a little loose.
- Put in the motherboard a spent battery.
- Apply too little thermal paste on cpu.
- Loose connections or get them dirty.